# How to receive a tick tuple since we start the topology?

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have a topology that is running in a cluster that receives a tick tuple every hour, the problem we are facing is that when we start the topology, we have to wait an hour to receive it and we want it since the moment that the topology starts.

Is there a way to receive the tick tuple since we start the topology?

Is there no way to do it? Is there a way to manually send a tick tuple to the bolt?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to manually trigger tick tuples, no. If I understand correctly, you want to run some code on tick tuples, and also when the topology starts? If so, why can't you run your code in the prepare/open methods for bolts/spouts, since these run during initialization?

Comment: But if the topology rebalances it will execute the prepare method again isn't ?

Comment: Yes, if the worker restarts for any reason, the prepare methods for the bolts running in that worker will run again.

Comment: Just to make clear, tick tuples aren't global. Tick tuples run inside the worker, so if the worker restarts, it will also reset your tick tuple timer.